# JAVA fatal error when writing Python Flask API

Tags: java, python, flask, fatal-error

i made flask + python + zerodb afgh => afgh api

and used postman to test api, but occur java fatal error when calling afgh method

zerodb afgh is python code using jar

i try to `ulimit -c unlimited` `export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx4096m`

but it's not works.

my environment : windows10, ubuntu 16.04(install windows app), 16G ram, python2.7, java

my error :

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f989dec6d70, pid=5720, tid=0x00007f9889400700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_181-b13) (build 1.8.0_181-8u181-b13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-b13)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.181-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [_jpype.so+0x2fd70]  JPJavaEnv::FindClass(char const*)+0x20
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /mnt/c/Users/hs/test/flaskrest/core or core.5720
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

more log : https://github.com/rkdlrl/flaskrest/blob/master/hs_err_pid5720.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

github.com/jpype-project/jpype/issues/279

using attachThreadToJVM() before afgh code